# How to mimic the Android default browser on my Desktop with Firefox or Chrome

Tags: android, firefox

How can I mimic the Android default browser on my Desktop with Firefox or Chrome? I've noticed that Google's search results, as well as other sites, sometimes look different on the Stock Android browser than other mobile browsers.

Can I change the userAgent to do something like this so I can view things on my desktop as on my phone?